# Can cache folder in Symfony be deleted without side effect?

Tags: symfony1

As far as I know, the cache folder ( that's located along apps, config, data lib and other folders) in Symfony project are just storage folder. Can I choose not to check it into my source control? Will my action has adverse effect on the completeness of my check-in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can delete the contents of the cache directory, but not the directory itself. The cache folder must have special permissions so that both the user and the webserver can write to it. Thus, you should have your source control ignore everything inside the cache folder, but not the cache folder itself.